# how to exchange the middle letter and last letter switched?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ask the user for the input of a word with a minimum of 3 characters. Take that word and exchange the MIDDLE letter with the LAST letter of the word.
If the word is an even number of characters long, take the letter to the right of middle (IE if a word is 6 letters long, you want the 4th character: “switch” is 6 characters and we’d want the ‘t’ as our middle character.
Output to the user their newly rearranged word.
*additional difficulty perform a check that the word is at LEAST 3 letters and display a message that it’s not long enough if something shorter than 3 characters is displayed.strong text

can you guys help me with this?

My code so far:

```
word=input('Please enter a word with a minimum of 3 characters')
word_length=len(word)
word_middle_index = int(word_length//2)
print('The letter in the middle of the word "'+word+'" is: 
word[word_middle_index])
```

this is how much I've done

Comment: Have you given it a try? Could you show us some effort so we know we're not just doing it for you?

Comment: ok, that is a good start.   Now try to figure out how to do it differently _if_ the word is of even length or odd length.

Answer (score 1):

this function will complete the task for you:

```
def switch_mid_and_last(word):
    if len(word) < 3:
        return("too short word")
    else:
        mid_letter = len(word)//2
        new_word = word[:mid_letter] + word[-1] + word[mid_letter+1:-1] + word[mid_letter]

return(new_word)
```

the outputs for the next inputs are:

```
print(switch_mid_and_last("ab"))
>>> too short word
print(switch_mid_and_last("abc"))
>>> acb
print(switch_mid_and_last("abcd"))
>>> abdc
print(switch_mid_and_last("abcde"))
>>> abedc
print(switch_mid_and_last("abcdef"))
>>> abcfed
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done it so that you can learn how to approach such a problem :

I'd recommend looking into a couple things online :

- `len` function
- `%` operator
- [:] operator

For instance :

- `n % 2 == 0` is True when is even.
- "abcd"[1:4] returns "bcd"

```
word = input("Enter A Word: ")

if len(word) < 3:
    print("The word length as to be more than 3 characters")
else:
    newWord = ""

    middleLetterIndex = 0
    lastLetterIndex = len(word) - 1

    if len(word) % 2 == 0: # even
        middleLetterIndex = int(len(word) / 2) + 1
    else:
        middleLetterIndex = int(len(word) / 2)

    middleLetter = word[middleLetterIndex]
    lastLetter = word[lastLetterIndex]

    newWord = word[:middleLetterIndex]
    newWord += lastLetter
    newWord += word[middleLetterIndex+1:lastLetterIndex]
    newWord += middleLetter

    print(newWord)
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

For making this easier to grasp, I haven't used any functions, classes, encapsulations or DRY principle here. Since you wanted to show helpful messages in each case, I have also added them.

```py
while True:
    word = input("Put a word with at least 3 letters: ")

    # check if the word has at least 3 letters
    if len(word) < 3:
        print("Word needs to be at least 3 letters long!!")
        break

    # check odd
    if not len(word) % 2 == 0:
        print("Word length is odd!!!")

        # make a list of letters
        word_lst = [letter for letter in word]

        # mid index
        mid_ix = (len(word) - 1) // 2

        # last index
        last_ix = len(word) - 1

        # swap middle and last character
        word_lst[mid_ix], word_lst[last_ix] = word_lst[last_ix], word_lst[mid_ix]

        # make the list into a string again
        word = "".join(word_lst)

        print(word)
        break

    # check even
    else:
        print("Word length is even!!!")

        # make a list of letters
        word_lst = [letter for letter in word]

        # mid index
        mid_ix = (len(word) - 1) // 2 + 1

        # last index
        last_ix = len(word) - 1

        # swap middle and last character
        word_lst[mid_ix], word_lst[last_ix] = word_lst[last_ix], word_lst[mid_ix]

        # make the list into a string again
        word = "".join(word_lst)

        print(word)
        break
```